# How to Change Css coding with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to change CSS with a link. What I'm trying to do is I want to change the `display:none` so it shows the page and hides another so it looks like your going to another page but it's already been loaded. Is it possible?

If it's possible with JavaScript or jQuery, how do I put it in HTML?

Can OnClick change display:none to display:block?

Comment: No, you would need Javascript to do this.

Comment: This can be done in javascript/jquery, but not css alone.

Comment: It is possible with Javascript, you can use jQuery for ease, take a look at http://jquery.com/. However if you can paste us some code of what you've already try that would be great for helping you

Comment: how do i do it with java scipt or jquery?

Comment: This might be able with scroll locks but they the initial load time would be extremely high.

Comment: http://try.jquery.com

Comment: After page laod or on same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:target` pseudo-class I think.

You could something like this:

```
<a href="#books">Show books</a>
<a href="#tv">Show TV</a>

<section id="books"></section>
<section id="tv"></section>
```

And CSS:

```
section {
  display: none;
}

*:target {
  display: block;
}
```

There are a few good examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

But I think, is most cases, using **JavaScript** would be a better solution.

**Edit**: added universal selector like [Alexxus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1574088/alexxus) suggested.

Comment: +1. This actually works. Nice! :-) But you have to do something like `*:target { display: block; }` to avoid typing out every id in your CSS. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexxus/pKdat/1/). But I think, jQuery is the way to go

Comment: @Alexxus using universal selector is a great idea. Will edit that. And yes, `target` as some limitations after all.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery then you could do a very simple click event like below...

`<a id="some_link" href="#">click here</a>`

```
$('#some_link').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('#page_two').show();
    $('#page_one').hide();

});
```

The prevent default is there to stop the link reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change visibility with jQuery. To hide an element you can use [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). To make an element visible you can use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Or you can use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which simply toggles the visibility.

If you have to change more than the visibility of an element, you can use the jQuery [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

Or you can use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to add or remove the css classes of an element.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, despite the comments saying otherwise, there *are* ways of doing what you want in pure CSS.

The best trick relies on having hidden radio buttons, and having the label for the radio button as the button that the user clicks. This could be styled as a button or a tab, or however else you want to present it.

In your CSS, you then use the `:checked` selector to toggle the visibility, etc.

There are a few other techniques as well, but that's probably the best for most cases.

[Here's a site that demonstrates it in action and explains it in more detail](http://www.mdawson.net/csstips/purecsstabs.php).

The only caveat I would raise is possible compatibility issues with older browsers. If you need to support browsers as old as IE7, then it's a near certainty that you won't be able to use any pure CSS technique, and will have to rely on javascript.

That's not to say the javascript solutions are a bad thing -- you may find that they're exactly what you want, especially if you want to do additional stuff like actually loading the content when the buttons are clicked, rather than just toggling visibility. CSS alone definitely won't do that.

Hope that helps.